# How to know the parameter value in shlex.split

Tags: python, pipe, quote, shlex

I have string variable as `--test abc -a a -b b c`, which is parameters for my linux script.

I am using python `subprocess` to execute this.

This string might be have `special` character like `backtic` or `'`, `--test \"it's my test\" -a a -b b c` in this case, I have to use `pipes.quote` to quote the value.

I can split this using `shlex.split` and get the paramters splited, I want to know that

```
In [21]: shlex.split("--test \"it's my test\" -a a -b b c")
Out[21]: ['--test', "it's my test", '-a', 'a', '-b', 'b', 'c']
```

From the list or `shlex.split` how can I check, which is value and which is the parameter?

I can check `startswith('-') or startswith('--')`, but is there any chance, it this logic might be wrong ?

Comment: Yes: it is entirely up to the program receiving the arguments to interpret some of them as options. For instance, `-test` could be a single option named `test`, or it could be interpreted as a shortcut for `-t -e -s -t`. It might use some character other than `-` to indicate an option; `argparse` itself supports this. Why do you need to identify options?

Comment: Thanks Chepner, If I am using `shell script` then my approch is right ?

Comment: @chepner as i mentioned, I need to apply `pipe.quote` so it will not break the process with special character.